# Need a list of past event participants and several years are gray, can't access them

Tags: civievent, civireport

when i search for events they all show up, but some of them are grayed out and I can't access any information:  I get this error--

An error has occurred.
0   @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css); @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/crm-i.css); @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);    Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred. You do not have permission to access this page.

[Return to home page.](https://www.seatuck.org/administrator/)

function toggle( element ) { var parent = element.parentNode; var className = parent.className; if ( className == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block') { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } else { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } }

Comment: The error says "You do not have permission to access this page". Check if you have enough permissions set up.

Comment: It might be you don't have the "Edit all events" civicrm permission.